# Flexslider ProgressBar pause issue

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am having a problem making the ProgressBar pause on hover and play on mouseout with Flexslider, When i pause the Flexslider there is always a delay bitween Flexslider image and ProgressBar, How can i make the ProgressBar and Flexslider image load at the same time.

HERE IS THE CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/rhPWJ/39/

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
 jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
 animation: "fade",
 controlNav: false,
 useCSS: false,
 controlNav: false,
 directionNav: false,
 pauseOnHover: true,
 smoothHeight: true,

 animationSpeed: 1800,

 after: function(slider) {
 jQuery('.slide-caption').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 700);
 },

 before: function(slider) {
 jQuery('.slide-caption').hide("fade", 1800); 
 },

 });
 });

 jQuery(window).load(function() {
 function run() {
 jQuery('.progress_bar').animate({'width': "50%"}, 4000, run).width(0);
 }
 run();

  jQuery('.flexslider').hover(
         function() {
         jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider('pause');
         jQuery('.progress_bar').pause();
         });

         jQuery('.flexslider').mouseout(
         function() {
         jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider('play');
         jQuery('.progress_bar').resume();
         });
 });
```

Comment: I think the problem is flexslider. if you use "play" it restarts the timer for the animation that's why the progressbar is out of sync. I don't see how u can fix this except with some code around. like you check the time from the start and set the animation time to the difference between your defined time and the time passed til hover. But don't forget to reset the time when a new slide is starting..

Comment: i'll have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work, CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/rhPWJ/92/

```
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({

          animation: "fade",
          easing: "jswing",
          controlNav: false,
          useCSS: false,
          pauseOnAction: false,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          smoothHeight: true,
          controlNav: false,
          directionNav: false,
          slideshowSpeed: 5000,
          animationSpeed: 1800,

          // animate caption
          after: function(slider) { 
          jQuery('.slide-caption').show("slide", { direction: "down"}, 700);
          },

          before: function(slider) {  
          jQuery('.slide-caption').hide("fade", 1800);
          },

          // image loader
          start: function(slider) {
          slider.removeClass('loading');
          }
          });

          jQuery('.slide-caption').show("slide", { direction: "down"}, 700);

          function run() {
          jQuery('.progress_bar').animate({'width': "300px"}, 5000, run).width(0);
          }
          run();

         jQuery('.flexslider').hover(
         function() {
         jQuery('.progress_bar').pause();
         });

         jQuery('.flexslider').mouseout(
         function() {
         jQuery('.progress_bar').animate({'width': "300px"}, 5000, run).width(0);
         });
         });
```